# NVidia triple monitor - xorg.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, xserver

I have got a new video configuration, and I would like to set it up properly:
1 - Monitor 1 (DVI connector)
2 - Monitor 2 (VGA connector
3 - Projector 1920 x 1080 (HDMI connector)

The video card is NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]

I would like to set it up using each monitor as one X screen.
how can i fix this problem.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).